# Writing a Matrix as a sum of squares

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, factoring

Currently I am attempting to write a matrix as a sum of squares. The matrix in question is as follows:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Given the matrix is of rank 2, I presume the result will be composed as a sum of two squares. Furthermore, I have found a correlation with previous matrices such as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which is a rank 1 matrix that reduces to:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where if each column correlates to a variable x, y, and z respectively yields $(x + y + z)^2$ which multiplies out to $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy + 2xz + 2yz$, matching the form $x^TAx$ where $x$ is a vector of variables.

Attempting to solve this way for my given matrix has given me $2x^2 + 2y^2 + 2z^2 -2xy - 2xz - 2yz$, however, I am not sure how to factor this into a sum of two squares.

Reducing the matrix has netted:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 1.5 & -1.5 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which has not exactly been conductive to much that I am aware of.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Since the matrix is singular, it can be written as just two square, with coefficients

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

=====================================================================

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$